# how to locally save multiple address with shared preference flutter

Tags: flutter, save, local

i have a form to get user name , phonenumber, street , province and i want to save this in local with Shared Preferences like this to read i have card for each adress inside tha  card it will show the details of the card so how can i do that?

```
{
"address1": {
    "name": "afthal",
    "phonenumber": "123456",
    "street": "197/F",
    "province": "Puttalam"
},
"address2": {
    "name": "afthal",
    "phonenumber": "123456",
    "street": "617/E Mannar",
    "province": "Colombo"
},
"address3": {
    "name": "afthal",
    "phonenumber": "123456",
    "street": "45 UC Road",
    "province": "Jaffna"
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope you are fine,

The best solution is to use a local database, but if you insist to use shared preferences, you can do this approach:

1. Encode the JSON and convert it to String.
2. Save the string in the SharedPref.
3. When you want to retrieve it -> get the String from SharedPref -> use json decode to decode it -> you will get. the Map (JSON) -> convert it to a list of addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution:

Instead of storing each address card in the local database, try to convert your `Address Card List` to `String` and store this `String` in `Shared Preferences` which contains all addresses.